# Repeated attempts to install geopandas gives same result

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, geopandas

I've attempted to install geopandas on my Jupyter notebook using several methods I've found on the internet.

I've tried: 
(1) Installing geopandas the 'normal' way: `conda install geopandas` 
(2) Using the conda forge channel: `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas` 
(3) To install a new environment to avoid potential dependancy conflicts (which is what my errors were reporting):

```
conda create -n geo_env
conda activate geo_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install python=3 geopandas``
```

Every single one of these attempts gives me the same error in Jupyter :
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'`

I've checked if the geopandas module is even in the system: 
`import sys`  
`'geopandas' in sys.modules` 
`>>> False`

The error in my anaconda prompt are all quite similar, all reporting conflicts of some package, I include two examples below.

```
Package rsa conflicts for:
google-cloud-storage -> google-auth[version='>=1.11.0,<2.0dev'] -> rsa[version='>=3.1.4,<4.1|>=3.1.4,<5']
google-api-core -> google-auth[version='>=1.14.0,<2.0.0dev'] -> rsa[version='>=3.1.4,<4.1|>=3.1.4,<5']
google-auth -> rsa[version='>=3.1.4,<4.1|>=3.1.4,<5']

Package google-cloud-core conflicts for:
smart_open -> google-cloud-storage -> google-cloud-core[version='>=1.2.0,<2.0dev|>=1.4.1,<2.0dev']
google-cloud-storage -> google-cloud-core[version='>=1.2.0,<2.0dev|>=1.4.1,<2.0dev']
```

After every attempt at installing a package, I restart the kernel or exit Jupyter entirely and go back in. I've also tried restarting my laptop (twice), all leading me to the same error of `ModuleNotFoundError`

Where am I going wrong?

I'm trying to install geopandas to plot latitude and longitude co-ordinates.
What are some other packages that could do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `ipykernel` installed in the env? How do you verify the correct environment is being used as the active kernel?

Comment: It wasn't before. I installed it, restared the kernel, the same error still appears.

Comment: You need to also select the newly configured kernel that belongs to your environment.